# add hdf5 libs (java & c++) to public maven repository?

Tags: maven, netbeans, hdf5

Is there a public maven repository where I or somebody can put the HDF java and HDF C++ libraries? I don't have a maven repository and I don't want to set one up myself for just these 3rd party libraries. More people must be using the HDF libraries and want to use them as part of a maven project.

http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf-java-html/

Is it even possible to put native c++ libraries (*.so files) in to a maven repository? Or is there another way that I can put them into a maven project in netbeans?

In the end I want to assemble (Maven Assembly Plugin) the tool that I've made (a converter for a specific HDF format) in to a single jar file so that it is easy to distribute the tool. It also would make it easier for other people to work on the source code of my tool and for them to build there own version.

The tool is programmed against the HDF java libraries, and these java libraries need the HDF c++ libraries to be on the javaPath.

Comment: Did you ever find an solution to your problem? I would like to know this as well. I haven't found anything that unambiguously says how JNI code might exist in Maven.

Comment: I should add that there is a [version up on Maven](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/central/org.hdfgroup/hdf-java/2.6.1), but it's old and I'm not entirely sure it looks like it has everything.

Comment: I tried to find a solution to this problem in a different thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753363/hdf5-in-maven-project